# WCF to solr get CSV

Tags: wcf, solr, export-to-csv

I need to export a large set of records from a page that is using `Solr` to query and get the data.
Currently I am stuck at how to get the Data from `solr` which is in `wt=CSV` using `WCF` and use a string formatter on that data to replace the titles for the `csv` and write it on my local hard drive. can someone point me at the right direction?